# How to use $index to iterate through ng-repeat JSON obj?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, indexof

How can I use $index to iterate suite no as in my code?

I have tried the followings:

```
<tr ng-repeat="spec in results track by $index">
                <td> {{$index + 1}} </td>
                <td>{{ spec[('suite'+$index)].id }}</td>
               <!--  <td>{{ spec[('suite'+$index+1)].id }}</td> -->
</tr>
```

.......

```
[

    {
        "suite1": {

        },
        "timestamp": "2017-04-27T12:30:53.051Z"
    }, {
        "suite2": {

        },
        "timestamp": "2017-04-27T12:42:24.227Z"
    }, {
        "suite3": {

        }
        "timestamp": "2017-04-27T12:49:42.070Z"
    }, {
        "suite3": {

        },
        "timestamp": "2017-04-28T04:18:51.585Z"
    }
]
```

For some reason, it works only for the first iteration. It iterates ONLY suite 1, and that's it. 
If I explicitly call for {{ spec['suite3'].id }} it iterates, and display all "suite3" items.

I must be doing something wrong here, I just can't figure out what is it.

Comment: is given json is of results ?

Comment: this is the JSON, yes. I can show a bit more complex JSON with under sub elements, but this is the basic skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like this,

```
  <td>{{ spec[('suite'+($index+1))].id }}</td>
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
$scope.results=  [

    {
        "suite1": {
             "id":1
        },
        "timestamp": "2017-04-27T12:30:53.051Z"
    }, {
        "suite2": {
            "id":2
        },
        "timestamp": "2017-04-27T12:42:24.227Z"
    }, {
        "suite3": {

        },
        "timestamp": "2017-04-27T12:49:42.070Z"
    }, {
        "suite3": {

        },
        "timestamp": "2017-04-28T04:18:51.585Z"
    }
];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app"> 
 <div ng-controller="Controller">
  <table border='1'>
   <tr ng-repeat="spec in results track by $index">
        
    <td>  {{$index + 1}} </td>
   
     <td>{{ spec[('suite'+($index+1))].id }}</td> 
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 <script type=" text/javascript " src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js "> 
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can I get suite 3 two times, in this case? (it shows only once) or, to get the count on how many suite3 items are there.

Comment: what do you mean by 3 times?

Comment: if you notice, I have suite1, suite2, suite3, suite3 as names. I would like to display the count of how many suite suite3 objects are there as well.

Comment: still i am not clear. you want to display suit1 1 time, suit 2 2 times etc?

Comment: I want to display the suite no, and count how many times a specific suite it's iterating itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="spec in results track by $index">
                <td> {{$index + 1}} </td>

                <td>{{ spec['suite'+($index+1)].id }}</td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Can I get suite 3 two times, in my case? (it shows only once) or, to get the count on how many suite3 items are there.